# C++11 non-static data member uniform initialization fails for pointers to other classes of same base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm an old C-dude that tries to learn about C++11 by porting my old state-machine framework from C to C++11. My idea is to have a class for the state-machine itself and then nested classes for the states within. The states may be hierarchical, i.e. super- and substates. The framework needs to know about a state's superstate and for that I have a pointer (`state *superstate`) in the nested state class.

My problem is that I intended to set the superstate-pointer by using the constructor directly within the machine's class, which should be possible in C++11 with non-static data member initialization, by using uniform initialization. But some reason it fails to compile (`substateB3{superstateA}`) when set to another type of state/class. But it works fine if I later set it by using a specific function (`set_superstate`) for this purpose, which has the same argument as the constructor! And funny enough the constructor is accepted if I set the superstate to a state/class of same type (`substateB2{substateB1}`).

I'm using gcc 4.7.0 (to get support for non-static data member initializers) and here's my code:

```
// My state-machine framework (simplified)
struct machine {
  struct state {
    state()                  : superstate(nullptr) { }     // No superstate => toplevel state!
    state(state &superstate) : superstate(&superstate) { }
    state *superstate;
    void set_superstate(state &superstate) { this->superstate = &superstate; } // Non-ctor way to set superstate
  };
};

// An example of a specific state-machine using my framework
struct Machine : machine {
  struct SuperstateA : state {
  } superstateA;

  struct SubstateB : state {
  } substateB1,              // Compiles OK; gets its superstate set in Machine's ctor below
    substateB2{substateB1},  // Compiles OK; but not correct superstate
    substateB3{superstateA}; // gcc 4.7.0 error: could not convert ‘{((Machine*)this)->Machine::superstateA}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘Machine::SubstateB’

  Machine()  { substateB1.set_superstate(superstateA); } // Compiles OK;
} myMachine;
```

Any tips or guidance are much appreciated thanks! :)

Comment: I understand that this is a learning exercise, but you may want to at least look at an existing modern C++ state machine framework such as [Boost.MSM](http://www.boost.org/libs/msm/) for some perspective.

Comment: In C++, please don't ever define a type and an object of the same type in the same statement. That's very confusing to read and unidiomatic.

Comment: Looks like you need inheriting constructors as well for your `SubstateB`. Not sure if GCC supports those already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripping one layer of inheritance:

```
struct m {
    struct state { state *s;
        state() : s(0) {};
        state(state &s) : s(&s) {}
        set(state &s) { this->s = &s; }
    };

    struct s1 : state {} A;   // calls s1(), the default constructor
    struct s2 : state {}    B     // calls s2(), ditto
    ,                       C{B}  // calls s2(const s2&), the default copy constructor
    ,                       D{A}; // calls s2(const s1&)

    m() { B.set(A); } // The m() body runs after all the members are constructed.
} M;
```

You're getting the construction error because your substates declare no constructors so they're getting the compiler-provided defaults, and there is none from a sibling- or base- class reference (the compiler doesn't provide `s2(s1&)` or `s2(state&)`).

You're getting the wrong superstate for `C` because `C{B}` invokes the default copy constructor `s2(s2&)`, which runs before `m()`'s body.

Here's what you want instead:

```
struct m {
    struct state { state *s; state() : s(0) {} state(state &s) : s(&s) {} };
    struct s1 : state {} A; // default-constructs, fine
    struct s2 : state {
        s2(state &s) : state(s) {}
        s2(s2&s)     : state(s) {}
    }            B     // default-constructs
    ,            C{B}  // calls s2(s2&), invokes state(state&)
    ,            D{A}; // calls s2(state&)
    ;
    m() : B(A) {};
} M;
```

When M's constructor runs, first its base classes (there are none) then its members are constructed in declaration order using the specified initializations.  There's only one: `B(A)`, so all the rest are defaulted.  After all the bases and members are constructed, then the object constructor's body runs.

Comment: Um, should have warned I did that from the keyboard, checking it now

Comment: As a remark a convenient way to normally solve the issue would be to inherit the constructor via a using declaration: `using state::state;`. However, as things are the particular constructor happens to be a copy constructor, which means that it can't be inherited -- an unforeseen accident I think. Just one constructor of the form `explicit state(state* p = nullptr);` would solve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I realize that in C++ constructors are not inherited - I was assuming that but this shows my lack of C++ knowledge ;) @LucDanton OK I can see that `using state::state;` should do the trick in C++11, which is great! But I checked gcc status and found it is no supported yet => I will have to stick to jtill's C++ approach or wait for support in C++11. Thanks both! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  struct SuperstateA : state {
  } superstateA;

  struct SubstateB : state {
  } substateB1, 
    substateB3{superstateA};
```

There is no relationship between `SuperstateA` and `SubstateB` that would allow casting or slicing between them. Even if `SuperstateA` were a base class (which is usually associated with "super"), `SubstateB` would still have more members (being a subclass) and it would be impossible to initialize them all from the object of different type.

It's not a bug in the compiler, or an arbitrary limitation of C++. It's simply impossible to perform that kind of initialization. There needs to be an "is-a" relationship.

On the other hand, both `superstateA` and `substateB1` can be cast to `state &` (or their pointers can be cast to `state *`), so providing `SubstateB::SubstateB( state & )` would patch all the holes quite nicely.

Comment: +1 Came here to say this but looks like I've written about everything except the issue. D'oh! :)